# No option to build a main hall in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have completed my small house in Hearthfire, and looking at the [official Wikia page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Hall), now I should have an option to start building the main hall:

> The Main Hall Is the second stage of home construction in The Elder
>   Scrolls V: Hearthfire and is only available after the Small House is
>   complete.

However, there is no option like that for me, I am only allowed to build some Misc items for the house, but there is no main hall design available yet.

[image]

What should I do to be able to start working on the main hall?

Comment: Isn't that done at the _drafting table_ rather than the _carpenter's workbench_?

Comment: @Svj0hn I think you are right XD I have spent so much time travelling around for items to build the parts of the house that I had completely forgotten that I had used the drafting table once :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Main Hall is an additional section of your house, and does not replace your small house.

[UESP Construction for a Main Hall](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Construction#Main_Hall)

You need to go to the drafting table first, select the main hall, and then build from there to complete it.